# How to use @Html.BeginRouteForm for search form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have form to search products:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Results", FormMethod.Get, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "navbar-form navbar-left", role = "search" }))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="txtSearch" class="form-control" placeholder="Products name..." />
        @Html.DropDownList("CategoryId", null, "Select category", new { @class = "form-control" })
        <select class="form-control" id="FromPrice" name="FromPrice">
            <option value="0">From price</option>
            <option value="2000000">2,000,000d</option>
            <option value="4000000">4,000,000d</option></select><select class="form-control" id="ToPrice" name="ToPrice">
            <option value="0">To price</option>
            <option value="2000000">2,000,000d</option>
            <option value="4000000">4,000,000d</option>
            <option value="6000000">6,000,000d</option>                    
        </select>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger form-control" value="Search" />
    </div>
}
```

And a route in RouteConfig file

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "SearchForm",
    url: "ket-qua/{txtSearch}-{CategoryId}-{FromPrice}-{ToPrice}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Results", action = "Search"}
)
```

How can i call the route "SearchForm" when i submit search form above with all of parameter.

Comment: `@Html.BeginRouteForm("SearchForm", FormMethod.Get)` however the values will be added as query string parameters, not route values (your browser knows nothing about your route definitions) so you will get `/Results/Search?txtSearch=abc&CategoryId=2&.....`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your routing code will like this.

```
     routes.MapRoute(
       name: "SearchForm",
       url: "ket-qua/",
       defaults: new { controller = "Results", action = "Search"}
      )
```

In your view code it will be like this.

```
@using (Html.BeginRouteForm("SearchForm", FormMethod.Get, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "navbar-form navbar-left", role = "search" }))
{
```

Your controller code will be like this way.

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Search(SearchModel model)
{

}

public class SearchModel
{
      public string txtSearch {get;set;}
      ----------------
}
```

If you want your url like that, you have to do that using javascript. And have to change controller code and view code.

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-danger form-control" value="Search" onclick="newDoc()" />

function newDoc() {
    //here you bind all your data
    window.location.assign("http://----------")
}
```

Comment: Thanks Anik Saha, as you teach, website work and url is http://localhost:65012/ket-qua?txtSearch=a&CategoryId=1&FromPrice=2000000&ToPrice=4000000. How can i do if i want url like this http://localhost:65012/ket-qua/a-1-2000000-4000000